# Github Error in pull/push for any private/public repo 2021 after update password to token in credential

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository, gitlab-ci

I have a huge problem with the new GitHub update on 13 AUG 2021.

I have a repo and I wanted to upload my new commit and I realized that GitHub changed its rules for uploading from password to token, So I generate a new token from my GitHub account and paste it into a password in github.com in Keychain address. And trying to push then it gives me an error:

> Permission to myUserName/app.git denied to myUserName.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myUserName/app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

So I delete everything in keychains that related to GitHub and trying to push again and gave me the same err after asking me about my username and password - (I tried to give it my real password and it gives me an err because pushing requires a token, Then I typed my token and give the same err above)

Even when I'm trying to pull my private repos it gave me the err below:

> remote: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyUserName/app.git/' not found

I've created a new repos and gave me the same errs. And I've just one account on my machine and GitHub also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by two things :

1- Should **enable two factor authentication** In github

2- In token setting it should to **Select scopes** to manage access In general So I checked **( repo, workflow and gist )**.